# NPM msbuild errors when trying to run

Tags: .net, npm, msbuild

I am running into an issue when trying to build my project using `NPM msbuild`. I seem to be getting the same error on some, but not all project files saying `foo.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "Restore" does not exist in the project.`.

I have done a decent amount of looking around and cant find a reason why this may be happening. I was wondering if anyone has ever run into this before, or might have a decent idea where to begin?

Comment: Did you look in `foo.csproj` for an MSBuild target called Restore?

Comment: @DanielMann - I guess if I knew where to look for it I would. Would you care to elaborate more?

Comment: CSProj files are text files. Open it up in an editor and look at it.

Comment: @DanielMann - Yup, Sorry I guess I was confused by what you were looking for exactly. I did that and did not find any Restore target. Thoughts?